# Compute the value of $\mathbb{P}_{0}\left[\tau\geq n\right]$ and $\mathbb{P}_{0}\left[\tau=+\infty\right]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

We consider the Markov chain $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n\geq0}$
  on $\mathbb{N}$
  whose transition matrix $P=\left(p_{k,l}\right)_{k,l\geq0}$
  given by

$$\forall k\in\mathbb{N}
  p_{k,0}=q_{k},p_{k,k+1}=p_{k}$$

with $p_{k}+q_{k}=1$
  and $p_{k}>0$
  for any $k\geq0$
 .

Assume that $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n\geq0}$
  is irreducible. Set $\tau=\textrm{inf}\left\{ n\geq1:X_{n}=0\right\}$ 
 (with the convention $\textrm{inf}\textrm{Ø}=+\infty$
 ); compute the value of $\mathbb{P}_{0}\left[\tau\geq n\right]$
  and $\mathbb{P}_{0}\left[\tau=+\infty\right]$

Give me some hints please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: To compute $\mathbb{P}_0(\tau\geq n)$, try to describe the paths that realize the event $\tau\geq n$.  For $\mathbb{P}_0(\tau=+\infty)$, use the monotone continuity of probabilities.

Comment: Wasn't the exact same advice given to you à propos your former question this one nearly duplicates? Surely you tried to follow it *then*... What happened when you did?